# Using jQuery and regex to validate fields

Tags: jquery, regex

I am following a video tutorial about JQuery. I copied the codes from the video and even copied and pasted the codes that came with the video to my text editor but, for some reason, it is not working on my machine but it is working on the instructional video though. When I put-in a value into the fields, it should check if it is a valid e-mail (using REGEX) and if another field is numeric and if the password fields match. If it doesn't then an error message would prompt me. The error is, it is accepting all of my input, it's not doing the prompting part.
 I do not know if it's a setting on my browser or machine or whatever that is causing this. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning jQuery</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#wrapper {
width:600px;
margin:0 auto;
font-family: helvetica;
font-size:1.2em;
}
input {
    width:300px;
height:30px;
padding:5px;
border-radius:5px;
font-size:1.2em;
border: 1px solid grey;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
label {
width:200px;
float:left;
padding-top:7px;
}
#submitButton {
height:50px;
margin-left:200px;
width:100px;
}
#error {
color:red;
margin:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="error"></div>
<form id="validationForm">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input name="email" id="email" />
<label for="phone">Telephone</label>
<input name="phone" id="phone" />
<label for="pass">Password</label>
<input name="pass" type="password" id="pass1" />
<label for="pass">Confirm Password</label>
<input name="pass" type="password" id="pass2" />
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
<script>
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
var errorMessage="";
event.preventDefault();
function
isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|
[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([az]|\
d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])
+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-
\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|
[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-
\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|
[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF
\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
if (!isValidEmailAddress($
("#email").val())) {
errorMessage="<br />Please enter a
valid email address";
}
if (!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val())) {
errorMessage=errorMessage+"<br />Please enter a valid phone number";
}
if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val()) {
errorMessage=errorMessage+"<br />Please enter matching passwords";
}
if (errorMessage=="") {
alert("Success!");
} else {
$("#error").html(errorMessage);
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post the error message.

Comment: The error is, it is accepting all of my input, it's not doing the prompting part.

Comment: Hi there - I tried pasting your code into jsbin.com and got a warning saying that I had an "unclosed regular expression".  Have you verified that you pasted the regular expression correctly?  It's very long, so I can see how it would be easy to make a mistake.

Comment: you need to check for the exact ranges here `[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]` see https://regex101.com/r/gV2vF1/1

Comment: But even without the regex, I still would have some error prompt if I don't input a numeric character in the phone field and error prompt when the password field and confirm password field does not match. I don't get any prompts. It seems that all of my fields "accept" what ever input I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tidy up somehow your code and managed to make it run. See the snippet below for details.

```js
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
      var errorMessage = "";
      event.preventDefault();

      function
      isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([az]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
      };
      if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val())) {
        errorMessage = "<br />Please enter a valid email address";
      }
      if (!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val())) {
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter a valid phone number";
      }
      if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val()) {
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter matching passwords";
      }
      if (errorMessage == "") {
        alert("Success!");
      } else {
        $("#error").html(errorMessage);
      }
    });
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
#submitButton {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
#error {
  color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning jQuery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form id="validationForm">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input name="email" id="email" />
      <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
      <input name="phone" id="phone" />
      <label for="pass">Password</label>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass1" />
      <label for="pass">Confirm Password</label>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass2" />
      <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What did you do?!? Thanks!!! It's working! Please tell me the error of my code. The tutorial that I got this from, as I see in the video, my previous code was supposed to work. Just like what I mentioned, I copied and pasted his code so I won't get spelling errors and the like but, it didn't work on my machine. But with the edited codes you made, it worked!

Comment: @user3825246 I think the cut and past has broke the code. Firstly, I put the regex on one line and not multiple lines. Secondly, the string `"Please enter a
valid email address"` was not closed correctly. That's all I do plus some tidying.